# Windows Phone 8.1 app error calling Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1 new Socket exception

Tags: sockets, silverlight, windows-phone-8.1

Environment: Windows 10 eval copy; VS 2013 Express Update3.

I created a Blank WP 8.1 app and a Windows Phone Silverlight Class Library. I added a class to the class library and in the constructor attempt to new a Socket. The Blank WP 8.1 app creates an instance of the class in its OnNavigatedTo event. That's the only change I made to the WP 8.1 app.

The call in the Class1 constructor generates the exception given below. This occurs in the Emulator 8.1 WVGA 4 inch 512MB.  Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

MainPage.xml.cs:

`protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    Class1 class1 = new Class1();
...`

namespace SockLib
{
    public class Class1
    {
        public Class1()
        {
            try
            {
                // The next line generates the exception.
                Socket sock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
                        SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}

A first chance exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in System.Net.ni.DLL
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at System.Net.Sockets.SocketNotificationManager..ctor()
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.get_SocketManager()
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket..ctor(AddressFamily addressFamily, SocketType socketType, ProtocolType protocolType)
   at SockLib.Class1..ctor()

Answer (score 0):

Will,

I suspect you cannot use OnNavigatedTo, because the UI is not built yet (and maybe something else, that have to do with the App capabilities on the phone). Would you try to use a button Click event handler to initialize your socket?

I have a very similar problem. I am trying to create a pure console application for WP8.1, and my Socket constructor fails the same way.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This sample works fine using VS 2012 Phone SDK and Phone 8.0 emulators on Windows Pro 8.1, which is what Windows 10 claims to be if you ask it. In fact you can create the class from the main constructor rather than OnNavigatedTo and it works fine.